# Algorithm to check consistency?

Tags: algorithm, math, statistics

Assume:

> There are hundred students and each on
>   of them are working on a common
>   project.

Ideally, being consistent implies that a student works everyday on the project at-least once.

If we have data like this:

```
Student 1  work      day 1(worked)
                     day 2(worked)
                     day 3(took a break)
etc
```

Now is there any algorithm that can be used to check and rank students based on consistency ?

```
   EDIT:
```

This is not a homework problem. I am developing a plugin in java that rates group work according to consistency. So I was wondering if there was an algorithm that can accurately predict consistency. I was thinking about using standard deviation but if there is something more precise, it would help.

Comment: "Consistency" is a very vague term.  If one student never showed up, that would be 100% consistent, but I'm guessing you don't want your algorithm to consider that a good behavior.

Comment: No it is not a homework problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the quantity you are looking for is called [variance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance). This describes consistency, if you were to say, use the time each day that a student works.

Comment: So can we say the student who has minimum variance is the most consistent.

Comment: @karpak: it depends on your definition of "consistent", but yes, this is one way to evaluate  consistency.